# Why are Pokestops missing on my phone but not my brother's?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I have a Pokestop right by my house, but its disappeared, no Pokemon in my area.

Funny thing, my brother plays and also has the same phone, and his works fine, 
We are on the same family plan, same phone, same team, heck we are same level cause we started the same time but only my phone is not showing any Pokestops, gyms, or nearby Pokemon.

Is anyone else having this problem, and/or know how to fix it? We've both got Samsung G7.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue on my IPhone. What I did was close the app through multi-task, put my phone into airplane mode, open the app, when it requested internet connection I disabled airplane mode.

Every time I have had this problem, this solution worked.